# render text on image with windows phone 8.1 - background agent

Tags: .net, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I need to draw string over image in background agent with windows phone 8.1, I can't find a way to start with.
Using rendertargetbitmap requires UI to works.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.XamlRenderingBackgroundTask**

Read more: [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/43295c90-43e8-4b08-8a25-958a1c3d0a0b/explanation-on-windowsuixamlmediaxamlrenderingbackgroundtask?forum=WindowsPhonePreviewSDK)